# Autocomplete SearchBar - Not a value cell

Tags: swift, autocomplete, uisearchbar

I am trying to implement a searchBar with autocomplete. I want when there is no value after I start typing, a cell "No results" to appear. But when I first select the searchField or when I delete all characters from it , the cell to disapear. I manage to make it appear when searchField is "" but I cant find a way to make it work like I described.

My code :

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchField: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet var autocompleteTableView: UITableView!

var pastUrls = ["Men", "Women", "Cats", "Dogs", "Children"]
var autocompleteUrls = [String]()
var searchActive : Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchField.delegate = self
    autocompleteTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    autocompleteTableView!.delegate = self
    autocompleteTableView!.dataSource = self
    autocompleteTableView!.scrollEnabled = true
    autocompleteTableView!.hidden = true
}


func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    autocompleteTableView.hidden = false
    let substring = (searchBar.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: text)
    searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring(substring)
    return true
}

func searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring(substring: String) {
    autocompleteUrls.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    for curString in pastUrls {
        if curString.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(substring) != nil {
            autocompleteUrls.append(curString)
        }
    }
    autocompleteTableView!.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return autocompleteUrls.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")

    if let _ = cell {
        let index = indexPath.row as Int
        cell!.textLabel!.text = autocompleteUrls[index]
    } else {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    return cell!

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check in your `numberOfRowsInSection` method if your array is empty and if it is return 1.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if autocompleteUrls.count != 0 {
        return autocompleteUrls.count
    }

    return 1

}
```

Further, you could use `DZNEmptyDataSet` from [GitHub](https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNEmptyDataSet) which is a nice set of delegate methods that will present something in your `tableView` if there is no data to display.